# Looking for the name of an old board game featuring a wolf, I think he was called Willy

Tags: identify-this-game

Looking for the name of an old board game featuring a wolf, I think he was called Willy. I can't remember much about it, but I played it a few times in the 80s, may have been older than that. It was quite scary for me because I was young. I think there was a figure of the wolf and there may have been a red and yellow piece for a player to choose. Does anyone remember this game?

Answer (score 5):

The [Uncle Wiggily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Wiggily_(board_game)) board game had colored pieces that moved on a track, and the "Fox Den" had an animal that looked like a wolf.  The game is filled with creatures, unfortunate events, and close calls that could frighten a small child.
[image: Uncle Wiggily Board]
[image: colored metal playing pieces]
[image: Plastic playing pieces and cards]
It was first published in 1916, but has been republished as recently as 1989.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [Beware of the Wolf](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/669149/beware-wolf):
[image: Beware of the Wolf]
Which features quite a big wolf in the middle of the board and is from the eighties (1981).